# Unable to find href of new window using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using below mentioned script to get href of new opened window, but its not working

Browser FF 7, IE 9, WIN 7

Can someone please let me know what's wrong in the script

Thanks in Advance

Akhil

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function open_win() 
    {
      var mywindow=window.open("http://thesun.co.uk");
      var clbutton=document.createElement("button");
      var par=document.getElementById("main");
      clbutton.setAttribute("id","focus");
      clbutton.setAttribute("value","CLICK");
      clbutton.innerHTML="CLICK";
      par.insertBefore(clbutton,null);
      clbutton.onclick=function() {alertMsg(mywindow);}
    }
    function alertMsg(mywindow)
    {
  mywindow.focus();
  var t=mywindow.location.href;
  alert(t);
  //mywindow.alert("testing");
  mywindow.close();
    }

    </script>
    </head>

      <body onload="open_win()">

         <p id="main"></p>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Do you happen to have "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/ from frame with URL..." or "mywindow is null" message in your console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the URL of sites that are in a different domain or protocol as the script that you are running.  It is due to cross-domain restrictions. Chrome gives you the following error:
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/ from frame with URL http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: is there any solution to this , i just checked in error console of FF its giving error : 'Permission denied to access property 'href'' , and also if i am using myWindow.onload='some alert function' then also alert coming much before actual thesun.co.uk page loads, seems like its not recognizing new window

Comment: Like the [`window.open` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) at MDC states your actions on a window opened with `window.open` are constrained by the [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).  There is no way around the same origin policy as it is an important security feature of all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it might be because the variable is not set yet. I think you might need a callback to say that the dom is ready for the new window.